# What mean T in formula?

Tags: matrices, dual-cone

I was reading a thesis ([this one](http://sci-hub.cc/10.1145/1344471.1344506)) when I came to some formulas with a T with came from nowhere. [image],[image], [image].

Could someone explain me what mean the T in these formulas ?

Comment: Likely Transpose - web blocker stops me from getting to link.

Comment: I think it could be this too. thanks !

Comment: It is. For example $x^TAx=\sum\limits_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j$.

Comment: It should be denoted in upshape, not like a variable. The traditional notation is a lowercase *prefixed* `t`, like this $\;^{\mathrm t\mkern-1.5mu}x A x$.

Comment: @Bernard "The traditional notation" Sure this is not simply the notation you were first exposed to? Or do you have any source supporting the "The"?

Comment: @Di: If  remember well, it's Bourbaki's historical notation.